# Can't update textview instantly

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I've a text view and a method has a while loop does things among them appending to text view 
But The text only changes when the method ends.. (but the console shows changes instantly 
How to update it instantly??

Comment: show code. cos now here coming genius and they cant help without code

Comment: It's a method with a while loop inside! come on!

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the UI, i.e., the gtk code, the chance to update the pixels on the screen. The update happens when your method exits because that is when gtk gets back in charge and can do the changes. If you want to do a lot of work and still update the UI just execute the work in a separate thread and update the UI by calling Gtk.Application.Invoke() from time to time.